# HTMLElement is suddenly undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

In the ngOnInit() mehtod, I'm getting an HTMLElement and using it to set a variable:

```
ngOnInit(){
this.popUpContainerDisplay = document.getElementById('popUpContainer');
console.log("pop", this.popUpContainerDisplay);
this.popUpAcceptContainerDisplay = document.getElementById('acceptPopUp');
this.popUpDeclineContainerDisplay = document.getElementById('declinePopUp');
this.popUpWarningContainerDisplay = document.getElementById('warningPopUp');
}
​

popUpFadeOut(): void{
if(this.popUpContainerDisplay.style.opacity == "0"){
console.log("fine", this.popUpContainerDisplay);
this.popUpContainerDisplay.style.opacity = "1";
this.popUpContainerDisplay.style.display = "block";

setTimeout(this.fade, 1000); //popup box fades away after 1 seconds
}
}

fade(): void {
console.log("notFine", this.popUpContainerDisplay);
this.newOpacity = parseInt(this.popUpContainerDisplay.style.opacity) - .01;
this.popUpContainerDisplay.style.opacity = String(this.newOpacity);

if (this.newOpacity <= 0)
{
this.popUpContainerDisplay.style.display = "none";
this.popUpContainerDisplay.style.opacity = "0";
}
else
{
requestAnimationFrame(this.fade);
}
}

constructor(private biddingService: BiddingService) {


biddingService.bids.subscribe(bid => {

if(bid.bidderArray){
this.bidderArray = bid.bidderArray; //.join('');
this.highestBid = bid.bid;

this.popUpContainerDisplay.style.display = bid.popUpContainerDisplay;
this.popUpContainerDisplay.style.opacity = bid.popUpContainerOpacity;  

this.popUpAcceptContainerDisplay = bid.popUpAcceptContainerDisplay;
this.popUpDeclineContainerDisplay = bid.popUpDeclineContainerDisplay;
this.popUpWarningContainerDisplay = bid.popUpWarningContainerDisplay;
this.arrayReset = bid.resetArrayBoolean;
this.popUpFadeOut();
}


});
}
```

ngOnInit() and popUpFadeOut() log the element in the console, but fade() logs 'undefined'. Why is the element suddenly undefined?

Comment: would be more pleasant to read if you sort out the indentation

Comment: @SamRedway Done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use arrow function to make sure that you context `this` inside of `fade` method will be instance of your component:

```
setTimeout(() => this.fade(), 1000);
```

or

```
fade = () => {
  console.log("notFine", this.popUpContainerDisplay);
  this.newOpacity = parseInt(this.popUpContainerDisplay.style.opacity) - .01;
```

See also other options here:

- [Angular2 injected Router is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41195034/angular2-injected-router-is-undefined/41195266#41195266)

Comment: Now the HTMLElement is not undefined anymore, but it says it "Cannot read property 'popUpContainerDisplay' of undefined" at console.log("notFine", this.popUpContainerDisplay); inside the fade() method.

Comment: What about `fade = () => {`?

Comment: Am I doing this right? https://gyazo.com/66c28e05b0888a76f79f6f196db226d1

Comment: No. I've added it to my answer

Comment: So like this? https://gyazo.com/354b12c58b43328461a0ebd03d280efd

It's giving me this error: (SystemJS) Unexpected strict mode reserved word(…)

Comment: No. `fade` method should stay in at the same place

Comment: I think that did it, thanks! Can you explain why fade = () => { } worked and fade(): void { } did not? :)

Comment: Check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130241/pass-correct-this-context-to-settimeout-callback