# cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined angular

Tags: angular

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import { GuessService } from './guess.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

declare var jQuery:any;
declare var $ :any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-guess',
  templateUrl: './guess.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./guess.component.css']
})
@Injectable()
export class GuessComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {


  }
  CheckLogin(name,pass)
  {

    $.ajax({
      headers:{  

   "Accept":"application/json",//depends on your api
    "Content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"//depends on your api
      },   url:"http://199.188.207.196:5555/user/login/",
      method:"post",
      data:{"email":name,"password":pass},
      success:function(response){

        if(response.success == true){
        console.log("ok");
        this.router.navigate(['/main']);
      }
        else{
          console.log("backend");
        }
      }
    });
  }    

}
```

When user click on CheckLogin **button** then it must route to **login component**, but in my side it show error.

I found **solution** of my question in stackoverflow but it's not working, i don't know what is the problem.

Comment: Post your template and whole component code

Comment: Its just a class , not even a component. Please post whole code

Comment: Is the router declared in the module?

Comment: I have added whole component

Comment: Define `success` as an arrow function: `success: (response) => { ... }`.

Comment: actually i am using jquery if i remove everything but this.router.navigate(['/main']); from CheckLogin function then it works fine

Comment: but i dont want that navigate work with jquery ajax anybody help me?

Comment: [You have lost the context of `this`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/%27this%27-in-TypeScript), is there a reason you are using jQuery ajax instead of Angular HttpModule?

Comment: HttpModule was showing error, so thats why i am using that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: So this one is showing an error too, isn't it? If you have problems with Http or HttpClient, I'd suggest to ask a question about that and figure it out. jQuery is unwelcome in Angular development, primarily because its use indicates that a dev isn't comfortable enough with Angular.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add => so that you can have the reference to the component.
e.g :

```
CheckLogin(name,pass) => {  
...  
}
```

this answer here was a pointer for me, it is still like a hack, you need to do things properly.
[Angular2 injected Router is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41195034/angular2-injected-router-is-undefined)

Comment: you mean like this `CheckLogin = (name,pass) => {...} `

Comment: Yes,using arrow functions, should be something like:
CheckLogin = (name,pass) => {
  ...
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Router, ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

export class GuessComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

CheckLogin(name,pass)
{
  this.router.navigate(['/login'], {relativeTo: this.route});
}
```